# sql sum join where group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

my SQLcode

```
select  ITM.Item_Code,
        ITM.Item_Description,
        --INV.QTY,
        SUM(INV.QTY) as 'Balance QTY',
        UN.Unit_Code
from    Inventory INV
join Items ITM on INV.Item_ID=ITM.Item_ID
join Units UN on ITM.Unit_ID=UN.Unit_ID
where INV.Type1 in ('GRN','DTN','DGRN','SR','RN','SVN') AND INV.Stors_ID_1='6'
group by INV.Item_ID
```

then execute, error

```
    Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Items.Item_Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

explain me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: At first, you should describe what do you want to achieve.

Comment: And Secondly, you should find out how `GROUP BY` works. You could find lot of results before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a correlated sub-query instead:

```
select  ITM.Item_Code,
        ITM.Item_Description,
        --INV.QTY,
        (select SUM(INV2.QTY) from Inventory INV2 where INV2.Item_ID = INV.Item_ID) as 'Balance QTY',
        UN.Unit_Code
from    Inventory INV
join Items ITM on INV.Item_ID=ITM.Item_ID
join Units UN on ITM.Unit_ID=UN.Unit_ID
where INV.Type1 in ('GRN','DTN','DGRN','SR','RN','SVN') AND INV.Stors_ID_1='6'
```

(The general GROUP BY rule says:
*If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.*)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  ITM.Item_Code,
    ITM.Item_Description,
    --INV.QTY,
    SUM(INV.QTY) as 'Balance QTY',
    UN.Unit_Code
   from    Inventory INV
     join Items ITM on INV.Item_ID=ITM.Item_ID
      join Units UN on ITM.Unit_ID=UN.Unit_ID
     where INV.Type1 in ('GRN','DTN','DGRN','SR','RN','SVN') AND INV.Stors_ID_1='6'
        group by INV.Item_ID,ITM.Item_Description,
```

Try the above query.

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY. (May however execute on older MySQL versions, returning an arbitrary result.)'

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because the columns `ITM.Item_Code`, `ITM.Item_Description` and `UN.Unit_Code` are in the `SELECT` but are neither arguments to aggregation functions (`MAX()`, `MIN()`, etc) nor are they in the `GROUP BY`.  The solution is easy

```
select ITM.Item_Code, ITM.Item_Description,
       SUM(INV.QTY) as [Balance QTY],
       UN.Unit_Code
from Inventory INV join
     items ITM 
     on INV.Item_ID = ITM.Item_ID join
     Units UN
     on ITM.Unit_ID = UN.Unit_ID
where INV.Type1 in ('GRN', 'DTN', 'DGRN', 'SR', 'RN', 'SVN') and
      INV.Stors_ID_1 = '6'
group by ITM.Item_Code, ITM.Item_Description, UN.Unit_Code;
```